# What's the actual meaning of the struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches in the struts2 convention plugin

Tags: configuration, struts2, convention

What's the actual meaning of the

```
struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches
```

in the struts2 convention plugin

Answer (score 0):

It allows (or should, I've never actually done it) finding actions without an explicit `@Action` annotation. For example, if an action didn't implement `Action` and wasn't annotated, it might not be picked up.